# How do I facilitate an asynchronous remote design sprint?

Tags: design

Has anyone figured a good method for facilitating an asynchronous (not the same time/place) remote design sprint? The typical design sprint happens synchronously (same time/place), and is done in-person with different stakeholders. I am trying to figure a good way to make this happen remotely using a tool like [Mural](http://mural.ly). The reason I ask about doing this asynchronously and remotely, is because many of the stakeholders are not at the same location, and our schedules are not flexible enough to block off an entire week for a design sprint.

I was thinking of creating a Mural board with an initial set of questions to be answered individually by stakeholders (session time-boxed to 2 days), and let the stakeholders come in at various points in time within those two days to contribute. This will continue for a couple weeks, with each session marking the five stages of the design sprint (Unpack, sketch, decide, prototype, test).

Comment: When you say asynchronous, what's the maximum difference in time you foresee? Just wondering why you'd refer to it a asynchronous than as taking place across different timezones.

Comment: Asynchronous vs synchronous is a term that is used in the eLearning circles. http://adulted.about.com/od/glossary/g/Asynchronous-Learning.htm

Comment: Right, but the question about time difference stands

Comment: It will not take place across different time zones. It could, but that is not the point. I do not wish to facilitate a design sprint in real-time (synchronously). I wish to do it while giving participants to think about their answers to the questions I will pose ahead of time. Then, they can come into the Mural board at a time that is convenient to them and make their contributions. They will be given a deadline to make their contribution (time-boxing). We will use Mural's dot voting feature to filter out the best ideas. Does anyone see any problems with this methodology?

Comment: Just my take, but we use the Kanban feature of JIRA, to do pretty much what you're describing, all the time. Our product and engineering teams are spread across the globe. I wish i had the flexibility to try Mural, looks very cool.

Comment: Mural is pretty free-form, I would be pretty careful in doing this asynchronously especially if people are not very experienced with the tool.  Generally, in my own experience, use of these applications need real-time feedback and guidance from someone knowledgeable with the tool to keep things organized.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible, because it takes a lot of cycles and therefore a lot of time to come to an agreement. Imagine that you have a complicated issue and you are emailing with support which is overseas. It is easier to call them.

I would suggest to agree something on the team level, create several proposals, select team members who can stay late or join via Skype and discuss the sprint content with the stakeholders with this smaller group. This group should be able to answer all the questions of the stakeholders and be able to make a decision if have to, so select wisely.